# Is there a way to redefine a LESS variable depending on the parent's class?

Tags: css, less

So I have this html markup

```
<div class="text-white">
    <div class="textClass"></div>
</div>
```

there's a Less defined variable for the class `textClass` that would turn the heading color to black but what I want is if the `textClass` element has a `text-white` parent then the `textClass` heading color would then turn to white. Is this possible?

This is what I have so far but it's not working:

```
//I defined the color of the heading
@heading-color: black;

//My attempt to redefine the heading-color base on class
.text-white > .textClass {
    @heading-color: white;
}
```

If this is not possible then how can I achieve this one using less?

Thank you for anyone that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can name the variable without `-` character inside, like this:

```
@headingColor: black;

.text-white > .textClass {
    @headingColor: white;
    background-color: @headingColor;
}
.some-heading {
    background-color: @headingColor;
}
```

Output:

```
.text-white > .textClass {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.some-heading {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Notice: when you override it, you can just use it inside the scope.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried this one but it doesn't seem to work. I think it's because the `@heading-color` is pre-defined since we're using a library. Is it possible to override pre-defined variables?

Comment: @ZyxSun Nope. It's working fine on [codepen](https://codepen.io/nguyennhuttan/pen/XWJepyv)

Comment: yeah it's working on the codepen. I think there's something in the library that we used since I can't override it using the example that you made. Anyway thanks!